Roslyn compiles code at runtime successfully but running the generated exe yields file not found exception
I get all the necessary assemblies like so
var rtPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(typeof(object).Assembly.Location) + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar;

string[] paths = [ rtPath + "System.Private.CoreLib.dll", rtPath + "System.Runtime.dll", rtPath + "System.Console.dll",
rtPath + "System.Text.RegularExpressions.dll", // IMPORTANT!
rtPath + "System.Linq.dll",
rtPath + "System.Linq.Expressions.dll", // IMPORTANT!

rtPath + "System.IO.dll",
rtPath + "System.Net.Primitives.dll",
rtPath + "System.Net.Http.dll",
rtPath + "System.Private.Uri.dll",
rtPath + "System.Reflection.dll",
rtPath + "System.ComponentModel.Primitives.dll",
rtPath + "System.Globalization.dll",
rtPath + "System.Collections.Concurrent.dll",
rtPath + "System.Collections.NonGeneric.dll",
rtPath + "Microsoft.CSharp.dll"];

var standardReferences = paths.Select(p => MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(p)).ToList();

Then I pass the code and the references to the method compiling the code like so:
var path = $"{Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop)}\\Roslyn\\test.exe"; 

var result = LoaderHost.CompileSourceToAssembly(@"
using System; public class Test {     public static void Main(string[] args)     {         Console.WriteLine(191);     } }", 
path, customReferences.Concat(standardReferences).ToArray());

The method I use:
  public static bool CompileSourceToAssembly(
      string sourceCode,
      string outputPath,
      params MetadataReference[] assemblies)
  {
      // Parse the source code
      SyntaxTree syntaxTree = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(sourceCode);

      // Define references to necessary assemblies
      var references = new List<MetadataReference>();

      foreach (var assembly in assemblies)
      {
          references.Add(assembly);
      }

      references.Add(MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(object).Assembly.Location));
      references.Add(MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(Console).Assembly.Location));
      references.Add(MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(System.Runtime.GCSettings).Assembly.Location));

      // Create a compilation object
      CSharpCompilation compilation = CSharpCompilation.Create(
          assemblyName: Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(outputPath),
          syntaxTrees: new[] { syntaxTree },
          references: references,
          options: new CSharpCompilationOptions(OutputKind.ConsoleApplication));

      // Emit the assembly to the specified file path
      using (var fs = new FileStream(outputPath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
      {
          EmitResult result = compilation.Emit(fs);

          if (!result.Success)
          {
              // Handle compilation errors
              foreach (Diagnostic diagnostic in result.Diagnostics)
              {
                  Console.WriteLine(diagnostic.ToString());
              }
              return false;
          }

          return true;
      }
  }

It  successfully compiles my code but upon starting the console app that was generated at runtime I am confronte with following exception:
Unbehandelte Ausnahme: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Die Datei oder Assembly "System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e" oder eine Abhängigkeit davon wurde nicht gefunden. Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden.
System.Private.CoreLib was not found, it states, though I clearly added a reference to it.
Anyone else having faced similar issues and managed to solve it?
